# Trying to find item that corresponds to the item in an array

Tags: python, arrays

The problem which I am facing is how I cannot seem to identify the selected item in an array list. It's kind of complicated. Basically, I want to loop 4 times and for every time it loops around the code, append the item, item number, its description and reserve price into one single array. However, because its looping 4 times the array Finallist seems to have appended all 4 of the items and the variables into its list. In doing so, causes my code on the final 3 lines. (i.e. Item = input("please enter your desired item") to not work, as the item the user enters will inevitably print the whole array list of the 4 items and its variables. However, I just want the variables in one loop. To make it clearer for you, for example if the program loops once, the item will be cat, its item number will be 123456, its description will be "cats are cute" and its reserve price is 1000, however, if I were to loop 4 times the program will have to print all 4 items and the variables, whereas I just want the single looped item and its variable. So I just want the item to be cat, and its item number to be 123456, its description to be "cats are cute" and its reserve price to be 1000, without the other 4 entries. I know the explanation may be confusing but I hope it makes it clearer for you. Thanks!

```
ItemNum = []
description = []
ReservePrice = []
item = []
NumOfBids = 0
Finallist = []

for count in range (0,4):
  user3 = input("please enter your item ")
  item.append(user3)
  user = input("please input your item number. ")
  ItemNum.append(user)
  user1 = input("Please enter your description for the product ")
  description.append(user1)
  user2 = input("Please enter your reserve price for the thing ")
  ReservePrice.append(user2)
  Finallist.extend(item)
  Finallist.extend(ItemNum)
  Finallist.extend(description)
  Finallist.extend(ReservePrice)

Item = input("please enter your desired item")
if Item == Finallist:
  print(Finallist)
```

Comment: `if Item == Finallist:` will never work. How can a single string be equal to a whole list?

Comment: And you shiouldn't extend `Finallist` every time through the loop. This will make 4 copies of the first item, 3 copies of the second item, 2 copies of the third item.

Comment: Why do you need all these lists? Put all the information about a single item into a tuple or dictionary, and then append that to one list.

Comment: I realized, just not sure how to go about it efficiently. Don't want to copy the loop 4 times just to get 4 lists. Cause its a task which we can't use dictionaries or multidimensional arrays.

Comment: Just use 1 list: `finallist.append({"item":, user3, "itemnum": user, "description": user1, "price", float(user2)})`.

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain what the {} brackets mean? When do you use it? I'm new.

Comment: Read a tutorial on Python dictionaries.

Comment: Oh, I mentioned before that I am not supposed to use dictionaries nor multidimensional arrays. Thanks for the advice though, will be useful in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a `if Item in Finallist:`.
 This checks wether a object with the value of `Item` is inside the list `Finallist`.

Forthermore why do you `.extend()` the `FinalList` ? Asimple `append()` would do the trick and avoid multiplication of occurence of data.

EDIT:

Here a modification of your code :

```
ItemNum = []
description = []
ReservePrice = []
item = []
NumOfBids = 0
Finallist = []

def print_item(item_list, item):
    start_index = item_list.index(item)
    print(item_list[start_index:start_index+4])

for count in range (0,4):
    user3 = input("please enter your item ")
    item.append(user3)
    user = input("please input your item number. ")
    ItemNum.append(user)
    user1 = input("Please enter your description for the product ")
    description.append(user1)
    user2 = input("Please enter your reserve price for the thing ")
    ReservePrice.append(user2)
    Finallist.append(user3)
    Finallist.append(user)
    Finallist.append(user1)
    Finallist.append(user2)

Item = input("please enter your desired item")
if Item in Finallist:
    print_item(Finallist, Item)
```

Edit :

Explanation of the `get_item()` function.

the function utilizes the so called list sliceing.

If you have a list like `example_list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]` 
we can acces "sub-lists" like `["c", "d"]` via `example_list[2:4]`

A slice works like `a_list[start:stop]`  which returns a list consisting of all entries of `a_list` within the indecees `start` and `stop` including the element with index `start` but excluding the item with index `stop`.

The Trick with the +4:

Since you have 4 entries which belong to a `Item` (`ItemName`, `ItemNum`, `description`, and `ReservePrice`) we allways want to find the intex of the `ItemName` and get it plus the next three entries BUT NOT THE 4th.
This is done by calling `.index(item)` this retrieves the index of `item`.
`item_list[start_index:start_index+4]` hence returns the sublist starting with `item` and ending with it's `ReservePrice` but does not include the next `ItemName`.

Further reading : [About Slicing](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/python-slicing)

Comment: Thanks for the correction, but i'm not allowed to use dictionaries or multidimensional arrays. Thanks anyways!

Comment: I think what you are suggesting is appending a list within a list, which makes it not 1 dimensional but 2 dimensional. Which means multi dimensional.

Comment: Pls see my edit which should clarify what i mean by using `.append()`

Comment: I see, thanks for the new edit. But the problem is that I want to print one of the loops in the 4 loops. E.g. If the entry was cats, 123456, cats are cute, 1000, but if you continue to enter, the result will be cats, 123456, cats are cute, 1000, dogs, 123456, dogs are cute, 2000 so the result will be individual elements in a list, but I want the final last three lines of the code to print the list relating to cats or dogs according to the Item defined by the user. So if I enter cats, the program will print 123456, cats are cute and 2000. My explanation might be a bit confusing. Sorry

Comment: AH you want the so called `(name, id, comment, int)` of the provided `Item` printed out ?

Comment: Yes. If possible without using a dictionary or multi dimensional array

Comment: Arguably, a `list` in a `list` is not a "multidimensional array". It's not even an "array". Anyway, are tuples in lists allowed?

Comment: I'm not sure, might need to check. But in the meantime I guess? I appreciate the suggestion, and will use it if allowed. Preferably, I would prefer an answer which only uses arrays just in case. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I kind of understand the +4 part, but due to my lack of python skills. Can you explain your function which you defined, especially the start_index part? Thanks so much.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I just have one more question (i'm new to functions) can you please explain the first and second line of why you need item_list?

Comment: Well, item_list is a function parameter. You pass the `Finallist` and the `Item` to the Function, in this order, within the function those become the variables `item_list` and `item`. We need those parameters within the function todo what we want.

Comment: I see your logic, but why can't we just use the variables Finallist and Item?

Comment: You can actually call the function parameters however you like. Nonetheless you should keep them as general as possible becauseyou might want to reuse this function a couple of times at completly diffrent occasions where this "namespacing" would be confusing."

Answer (score 0):

I removed some unnecessary cruft from the code snippet.

```
Finallist = []

for count in range (0,4):
    user1 = input("please enter your item ")
    user2 = input("please input your item number. ")
    user3 = input("Please enter your description for the product ")
    user4 = input("Please enter your reserve price for the thing ")
    Finallist.append(user1)
    Finallist.append(user2)
    Finallist.append(user3)
    Finallist.append(user4)

Item = input("please enter your desired item")
# check only every 4th item in the list
# if we found a match, print it and the next 3
for i range(0, len(Finallist), 4)
    if Item == Finallist[i]:
        print(Finallist[i], Finallist[i+1], Finallist[i+2], Finallist[i+3])
        break
```